# Не отображается index.html при запуске сервера django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Код `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import UserForm

def index(request):
    userform = UserForm()
    return render(request, "index.html", {"form": userform})
```

Код `Index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Django Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Код `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Но когда я запускаю сервер я получаю стартовую страницу django, а я хочу получить `index.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В urls.py должно быть прописано, какую функцию вызывать при обращении к определенному адресу.

К примеру, если нужно чтобы index открывался на главной странице вместо стартовой django:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index),
]
```

Подробнее [тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view)

Comment: Выдает TemplateDoesNotExist at /

Comment: "Код Index.html" Название файла написали с большой буквы. Может и в проекте такая же ошибка? Название файла шаблона должно быть такое же как и в функции index

Comment: В проекте с маленькой начинается

Comment: значит не там сохранили шаблон, он должен находиться в папке templates, если настройки стоят по умолчанию. Если все-равно не работает, попробуйте создать проект заново по инструкции https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/